# Imagemagick convert ultra slow

Tags: performance, imagemagick, gif

I'm trying to optimize a 8 seconds / 1.1 mb [gif](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sLZXuLrYuj3E9dNH2qSzCgnbZmw-KLNf/view?usp=sharing), it's taking more than 5 minutes on my mac and it doesn't finish, I just abort.

```
convert ep.gif -coalesce -layers Optimize ep-optimized.gif
```

Resource

```
>>> convert -list resources
Resource limits:
  Width: 461.169PP
  Height: 461.169PP
  Area: 17.1799GP
  List length: unlimited
  Memory: 8GiB
  Map: 16GiB
  Disk: unlimited
  File: 192
  Thread: 4
  Throttle: 0
  Time: unlimited
```

Comment: How big are the dimensions of the gif? When decompressed, your whole animation may be larger than your RAM allocation. What does `convert -list resource` tell you? Do you have enough RAM for how many frames you have all loaded into memory?  ImageMagick will try to load the whole 8 seconds of frames and then write the same number of frames. They are not read and processed one frame at a time.

Comment: When you run out of RAM, ImageMagick pages to disk and that is much slower.  If you are not on a shared server, then you can edit your ImageMagick policy.xml file to increase your RAM allocation up to the limit of the amount of RAM you have available.

Comment: The gif dimensions are `1644 × 810`, I edited the question to include the output of `convert -list resource`.

Answer (score 2):

A frame of your video is 1644x810x3 bytes, i.e. 4MB, if your **ImageMagick** was compiled at Q8. You can check with:

```
magick identify -version
Version: ImageMagick 7.1.0-5 Q16 x86_64 2021-08-22 https://imagemagick.org
```

You can see mine is Q16, so each frame is now 8MB.

Your GIF has 521 frames, so your minimum RAM requirement, just to load your image and not even start creating an output image, is:

```
1644x810x3x2x521 = 4GB
```

Checking memory usage on my machine, I get:

```
/usr/bin/time -l magick ep.gif -coalesce -layers Optimize ep-optimized.gif

  190.22 real      1568.54 user       102.18 sys
     17268342784  maximum resident set size        <--- 17 GB !!!
               0  average shared memory size
               0  average unshared data size
               0  average unshared stack size
        11073112  page reclaims
              14  page faults
               0  swaps
               0  block input operations
               0  block output operations
               0  messages sent
               0  messages received
               0  signals received
               1  voluntary context switches
        15028430  involuntary context switches
   4523216162264  instructions retired
   6123562866718  cycles elapsed
     17278709760  peak memory footprint
```

I think you either need to:

- recompile a Q8 version of **ImageMagick**, or
- allocate more RAM (if you have it), or
- target  a lower resolution or frame-rate, or
- consider using a different format - such as video.

Comment: By checking `magick --version` it's `Q16` like yours and it looks like it's currently installed by default in recent versions. I uninstalled, and re-built a `Q8` version, it's now showing `ImageMagick 7.1.0-7 Q8-HDRI x86_64`. I tried optimizing the gif again, the problem persists probably because I have limited memory `8 GB`.

Comment: There are other tools - `gifsicle` maybe?